# Animation is lost after converting png to webp

Tags: webp

I have an animated PNG image but after I convert it to webP - I get the static image without animation.

I've tried cwebp

```
$ cwebp -q 100 1.png -o 1.webp
$ cwebp -version
1.0.0
```

and the same with imagemagick

```
$ magick 1.png -quality 100 -define webp:lossless=true 1.webp
$ magick --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-29 Q16 x64 2020-09-05 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

How can I convert to save the animation?

Answer (score 0):

As discovered, cwebp does not support conversion with animation. Possible solution is to extract the individual frames (using ffmpeg or imagemagick for instance) and use img2webp to generate the animation.